# Sending xmpp message to facebook through sendxmpp

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

For some time I've been sending chat messages to users from certain ecommerce groups in facebook. I did this using the program `sendxmpp`. It worked fine until now. No error or warning is shown when I execute the program, but the message aren't send, except if I send a message to myself, then It does works.

```
echo 'Hola Solo Estilo Peluqueria!, somos programadores independientes de La Plata y estamos lanzando una nueva aplicacion para Android, para facilitar el comercio 
online dentro de la ciudad de manera segura e inteligente. Nuestra aplicacion, Lunula, te va a permitir vender y comprar lo que quieras en la ciudad 
de forma segura. Nos interesamos en vos porque vimos el anuncio que publicaste ("necesito lava cabeza para peluqeria! tienen?") en "Compra y venta la plata." y pensamos que por ahi te gustaría publicar ese mismo 
articulo en Lunula. Descargatela de acá http://lunula.co/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=messaging&utm_campaign=lunula o buscala en el Google 
Playstore como "Lunula", es completamente gratuita!' | sendxmpp -v -t 1428089740841785@chat.facebook.com
sendxmpp: config: 'password' => 'PASSWORD'
sendxmpp: config: 'jserver' => 'chat.facebook.com'
sendxmpp: config: 'component' => 'chat.facebook.com'
sendxmpp: config: 'port' => '0'
sendxmpp: config: 'username' => 'ID'
sendxmpp: ssl_verify: 1
sendxmpp: tls_ca_path: 
Use of uninitialized value within @_ in lc at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Stream/Parser.pm line 71.
Use of uninitialized value within @_ in lc at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Stream/Parser.pm line 71.
sendxmpp: Connect: 1
Use of uninitialized value within @_ in lc at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Stream/Parser.pm line 71.
sendxmpp: AuthSend: ok
sendxmpp: MessageSend
sendxmpp: Disconnect
```

This means that I got banned from the facebook chat, or is something else?

Comment: The Chat API has been removed. There is no way API for chatting

Comment: The chat API was removed yesterday? Because until then, It went working just fine.

Comment: Also, I don't think that is removed because even now, I can send xmpp messages to myself.

Comment: one of your apps may still be v1.0 then. but it will definitely upgrade to v2.0 in the next days, and then...well, see tobis answer.

Comment: The chat API was removed in API v2.0. Starting at 4/30/2015 we started forcing app into API v2.0. Over the next few weeks we will force all apps into v2.0 and after that no app can use the Chat API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_chat

> The Chat/XMPP service and API was deprecated along with Graph API v1.0 on April 30, 2015.